# Linux opencv independent installation : not found in CMake

Tags: linux, opencv, installation, linker, cmake

I am creating an object tracking program which rely on OpenCV. Thus I want to be able to test it with different versions of OpenCV but I have linking errors.

I installed the last version of OpenCV (a69b435c928f422fb5f99c02cf2dcae57dcf820a) in the following folder : `/usr/local/opencv/opencv-trunk` instead of the usual `/usr/local`.

Then I followed also the [official tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html#linux-gcc-usage) to use OpenCV with CMake in Linux, but I had the following "normal" error :

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

So I did what was suggested and added the following line in my `CMakeLists.txt` :

```
# Find independently installed OpenCV libraries
set(OpenCV_DIR "/usr/local/opencv/opencv-trunk/share/OpenCV")
```

This is the complete `CMakeLists.txt` file :

```
# Find independently installed OpenCV libraries
set(OpenCV_DIR "/usr/local/opencv/opencv-trunk/share/OpenCV")

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Now I have the following error and I don't find how to deal with it.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /usr/local/opencv/opencv-trunk/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake

  but it set OpenCV_FOUND to FALSE so package "OpenCV" is considered to be NOT FOUND.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

If you have already faced that issue in such context your solutions are welcomed ;)

Comment: Which opencv version are you using (beta 3.0 or stable 2.11) ? Any specific CMake version ?

Comment: It is the beta 3.0 version at state : a69b435c928f422fb5f99c02cf2dcae57dcf820a

Comment: cmake version 2.8.12.2

Answer (score 0):

If you are running IntelliJ or any other IDE, just try re-building CMake cache (or just remove your build directory and run `cmake` utility again).

I believe this is not the best practice - to set the configuration variable like `OpenCV_DIR` hard-coded in the `CMakeLists.txt`. Try setting it manually, as an environment variable to the `cmake` utility:

```
OpenCV_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_2/share/OpenCV/ cmake ..
```

or set your IDE to make this for you:

[image: CMake environmental variables in IntelliJ/CLion]

Comment: Thank you for the advice for the environment variable (Vim is my IDE ^^). I do not remember how I dealt with it though since it was quite a long time ago and I do not work there anymore.